# How to add parentheses in bison calculator?

Tags: bison, yacc

I am having trouble figuring out how I can add grouping symbols in a calculator made in bison. I have tried different solutions but all of them do not apply to my specific case. The issue I am mainly dealing with is finding out where to put the parentheses in the code itself so it can follow the GEMDAS rule.

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int yylex();
void yyerror(char const *s);
%}

%define parse.error verbose
%token NUMBER
%token ADD SUB MUL DIV EXPO OP CP 
%precedence NEG
%token EOL QUIT

%%
calclist:
| calclist exp EOL {printf("=%d\n", $2);}
| calclist QUIT {printf("Exitting..."); return 0;}
| error EOL {yyerrok;}
;

exp: factor
| exp ADD factor {$$ = $1 + $3;}
| exp SUB factor {$$ = $1 - $3;}
;
factor: term
| factor MUL term {$$ = $1 * $3;}
| factor DIV term {$$ = $1 / $3;}
;
term: exponent
| exponent EXPO term {$$ = pow($1, $3);}
;
exponent: group
| OP group exp CP {$$ = $2;}
;
group: NUMBER
| SUB group %prec NEG {$$ = -2;}
;
%%

void yyerror(char const *s){
fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", s);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv){
yyparse();
}
```

Here is the flex file

```
%{
#include "calc.h"
%}

NUM [0-9]+

%%
"+"             {return ADD;}
"-"             {return SUB;}
"/"             {return DIV;}
"*"             {return MUL;}
"**"            {return EXPO;}
"("             {return OP;}
")"             {return CP;}
{NUM}           {yylval = atoi(yytext); return NUMBER;}
\n              {return EOL;}
[[:space:]]     {}  
"exit"          {return QUIT;}
 .              {printf("\nUnrecognized string %c\n", *yytext);}
 %%
```

Comment: Add a rule to `exp` — `exp: OP exp CP { … } | …` or similar.

Comment: Just keep going with the rest of the standard expression grammar: `term : primary;` and `primary: number | '(' expression ')' ;`. For `primary` you have `group`: best to stick to the standard names, as found in any programming language grammar.